# Разработка проекта на WebGL в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, webgl

Столкнулся с непростой ситуацией. Заказчик заказал игровой симулятор, но с условием, что он будет работать в вебе. Было решено для первоначального этапа сделать проект на `WebGL` в `Unity`. Для показа сделали, все всем понравилось и сейчас решается вопрос начала разработки полным ходом. Симулятор делился на этапы (в `Unity` сцены), почти никак не связанные друг с другом.

Вопрос в том, как лучше реализовать такую задачу на `WebGL`?

Думал, как вариант, сделать каждый этап симулятора, как отдельную страницу сайта и просто инфу о завершении этапа передавать на сайт через функции `js`. Вроде бы все здорово, но получается, что на каждый этап игры получится отдельный проект в Unity. Это поможет, на мой взгляд, снизить количество ресурсов на одном этапе, но с другой стороны боюсь того момента, что у меня будет +100500 проектов в `Unity`. И когда придут правки по всем этапам, придется их все переделывать отдельно.

Может в Unity имеется возможность компилить и выгружать только определенные сцены с определенными ресурсами, используемыми на этой сцене? И насколько вообще будет реально выгружать с Unity проекта какой-нибудь файл типа `json` и делиться им с остальными этапами через `javascript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Может в Unity имеется возможность компилить и выгружать только определенные сцены с определенными ресурсами, используемыми на этой сцене?

В окне Build Settings можно выбрать те сцены, из которых нужно сделать сборку.
Unity будет собирать только те ресурсы, которые используются в этих сценах (плюс все из папки Assets/Resources).

> И насколько вообще будет реально выгружать с Unity проекта какой-нибудь файл типа json и делиться им с остальными этапами через javascript?

Межстраничный обмен между приложениями организовать сложнее, чем обмен внутри одной страницы одного приложения между сценами.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте AssetBundles для загрузки ресурсов с сервера или локального, это достаточно просто.

https://m.habr.com/ru/post/433366/